# Parameters user defined tabla type between linked server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have two SP each one into database correspondingly, one Sp recieve parameters user-defined table types but doesnt work.

Display the following error:

> The attempt by the provider to pass remote stored procedure parameters to remote server [linked server]  failed. Verify that the
>   number of parameters, the order, and the values passed are correct.

First Sp execute remote sp like this:

```
EXEC [linkedServer].[CCPMSG_DESA].dbo.SVA_GBR_OPE_SIS_SWP_WEB_SER_test 
     @TYPE_IGC_SWP_FIJ --Parameters user-defined tables type
```

Second Sp recieve parameters like this:

```
create procedure SVA_GBR_OPE_SIS_SWP_WEB_SER_TEST (     
    @TYPE_IGC_SWP_FIJ       TYPE_IGC_SWP_FIJ READONLY) 
as begin 

end
```

Exists any issue with this mode of work, or exists another way to do it?

Comment: You can't use table valued parameters across a linked server. There is no way to know that the parameter you created on the local database is the same as the remote one.

Comment: Bad news, I think that I should create other way like a web services.

Comment: Not sure how or why that is bad news?!?!? I guess you don't want or need help now??

Comment: Yes, what are the alternatives?

Comment: There are a zillion ways to deal with this. The simplest is to make a connection to the database where the procedure resides instead of across a link server. There are other ways too but they require a bit more trickery.